# Display posts in loop of specific authors

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, loops

Hi guys I'm in a bit of a problem on making a new wordpress website. I have a custom post type called "authors" where I place all authors that will create content in new website. Now after styling with CSS those single author sites I would like to make a loop, which will show their posts in website. How can I achieve that? Right now, when I use standard loop, it displays me posts of all user, but not that specific one, on which site I'm actually in. If it isn't achievable in that way, please tell me how to achieve it in easier way? Maybe I should delete the custom post type, and base on "users". But then how can I pick their "info" into loop (for example name, bio, and how many posts they have written already). Below the code of single-authors.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main class="author">
<div class="container">
<h1>Author's articles</h1>
<a href="" class="see-all">Meet our team <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<span>You are here:</span>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">INFO</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="entries-authors">
<div class="single-author row">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
 <img src="<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); print_r($thumb[0]); ?>" alt="">
 </a>
<div class="author-info">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<h3><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo substr($title, 0 , 100); ?>
</h3>
</a>
<h4>
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'job' );
if ( !is_wp_error($terms)) {
$album_categories = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$album_categories[] = $term->name;
$albums = join( ", ", $album_categories );
}
?>
<span><?php echo $albums; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
</h4>
<p>Follow me:</p>
<!--
<div class="author-social">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
-->
</div>
<div class="author-bio">
<div class="bio-desc">
<p class="more-toggle">
<?php 
echo get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
?>
</p>
<button class="toggle">Show more <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="genre-list"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/gamepad.png" alt="">Favourite genre:
<span class="genre-tags">
 <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->id, 'genre' );
if ( !is_wp_error($terms)) {
$album_categories = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$album_categories[] = $term->name;
$albums = join( ", ", $album_categories );
}
?>
<span><?php echo $albums; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="author-entries-count">
<span>Entries:</span>
<p href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="count">
<?php 
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
echo count_user_posts($post_author_id);
 ?>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<section class="articles">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#news">News (18)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#reviews">Reviews (2)</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#features">Features (6)</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="news" class="tab-pane fade in active">

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 7)); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php echo the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>


<div class="single-post">
<div class="thumb">
<img src="<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); print_r($thumb[0]); ?>" alt="">
<span>nintendo</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
<h2>Nintendo Explains Why Zelda Games Rarely Come Out on Time</h2>
<p>Some of the key designers behind Nintendo's famous Legend of Zelda series have spoken up to explain why new installments in the iconic... <a href="">Read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
<div class="news-info">
<div class="time-stamp">
<span>
<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>
</span>
</div>
<div class="comments-stamp">
<span>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/comments-gray.png" alt=""><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
 count_user_posts($post_author_id);
?>

</div>
<div id="reviews" class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
<div id="features" class="tab-pane fade">

</div>
</div>
</section>
<aside class="sidebar">
<sidebar>
<div class="hot-news">
<h3>hot topics</h3>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'hot_topics', 'posts_per_page' => 5)); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="single-hot-news">
<img src="<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); print_r($thumb[0]); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<h3><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo substr($title, 0 , 40); ?></h3>
</a>
<span><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/comments.png" alt=""><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<div class="show-more">
<a href="">See more</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="interesting-news">
<h3>You might be interested in</h3>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 5)); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="single-interesting-news">
<img src="<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full'); print_r($thumb[0]); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<h3><?php $title = get_the_title(); echo substr($title, 0 , 40); ?></h3>
</a>
<span><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/author-comments.png" alt=""><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<div class="show-more">
<a href="">See more</a>
</div>
</div>
</sidebar>
</aside>
</div>
</main>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That was what I needed

```
<?php query_posts('author=' . $post->post_author . '&order=ASC&showposts=7'); ?>
```